# CSS: Display property, block

Tags: css, header, block

I'm still learning how to do layouts with CSS.
After borrowing some CSS from another website to play with, 
I've noticed that if I remove this from the CSS:

```
header {  
    display: block;  
}
```

that my header will not center. If I remove this from the CSS file, the header image becomes very small and remains in the upper left corner. After reading about the display property, I can't see why it controls centering. Could someone simply/briefly explain it to me?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Scroll partway down the page for a detailed explanation and examples on what `display: block` does.

FYI: the code you posted won't necessarily do anything in browser parsing a document as HTML 4 (but will in a browser supporting HTML 5).

It states that a tag called "header" (which doesn't exist in HTML 4) should be set to `display: block`. Thus, one of four things will happen:

1. Browser will recognize it as HTML 5 and apply the style.
2. Browser will do an arbitrary pattern match and apply the style even though it doesn't know the tag.
3. Browser will do nothing.
4. Browser will only follow some of the CSS instructions.

EDIT: here is documentation on the new `header` tag in HTML 5: 
http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/

EDIT #2: *Barring any other conflicting styles on the page*, this will provide a centered heading.

```
<style>

H1 {
    text-align: center;
}

</style>

<h1>Some text to be centered</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

**display: block** means that the element is displayed as a block, as paragraphs and headers have always been. A block has some whitespace above and below it and tolerates no HTML elements next to it, except when ordered otherwise (by adding a float declaration to another element, for instance). [**more**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html)